# Is there a mature GUI library for D2 which does not rely on any DLLs (for windows only)

Tags: user-interface, d

I have a small firmware update program written in D which works great from the command line but I would like to give it a GUI. All a really need is a progress bar, a few dialogs and a status bar. It will only be deployed on Windows (XP to current) and I would like it to have as few dependencies as possible. Is there a GUI Library which is considered ready for production code that can be statically linked into one small exe? Or should I just use the naked windows API?

Comment: Lists of GUI libraries, maybe you find something to your liking ... http://wiki.dlang.org/GUI_Libraries and http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?action=browse&id=GuiLibraries

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16285105/2333136
Hope its not too late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are several, but DFL matches the best your description. More about DFL: http://www.dprogramming.com/dfl.php .

Comment: it's dead though last snapshot was released in 2011

Answer (score 0):

You can always go for [DWT](http://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt), which is a port of eclipse' SWT to D. It is cross platform, but as you only need to support Windows, you might as well use the native C API.
I would much more prefer to use DWT though.