# Updated GUI libraries for D in 2013?

Tags: user-interface, d

I'm developing a game in D. So far I really appreciate the D language, and for the most libraries there are good bindings. Now, for the editor I'm in search for a portable GUI library. wxD or DWT seemed like good options, but they seem abandoned, as the latest updates date from years ago. Also on the forum is not much life left.
Are there any frequently updated mature GUI libraries out there? Is D even worth going on with? Which language besides D is good for games?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if all else fails you could use a C library after porting the header files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are familiar with GTK, then that's your best option. When I tried GTKD, I had to spend several hours just to find out how to add stuff to a List interface! In year 2013, it should not take this much time to understand the api. (probably old design is the issue?).

I also used DWT & DFL, both are similar in ease of use but I consider DWT to be more maturely designed (as its inherited from SWT?). Finally I moved to DWT and never looked back, it API is very simple and easy to understand and one look at the docs and I knew exactly how to use it.

Also DWT it not abandoned, its home page moved to [Github](https://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt).

(I am not a GTKD or DWT developer. Just an user.)

Good luck

Comment: I ended up trying GtkD and QtD, one didn't compile, one is not native. DWT worked really well and is alive. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

GtkD is the most mature library: http://gtkd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I second to that. So far GtkD is the most active GUI project.